# Cascade delete from collections in multiple entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have three entities:  Customer, Device and LocationTag.

Customers have a list of LocationTags (nothing more than an ID and a Description).  They also have a list of Devices.

Devices are tagged with a subset of the Customer's LocationTags, so Devices have a List of LocationTags, too (but only of the Customer's).

If I delete a LocationTag from the Customer's list, I would like it also to cascade delete from the list of LocationTags in the Device.  Currently, I have it working but with manual code in the domain object classes, but violates DRY in my opinion.

**Is it possible to accomplish this via Fluent NHibernate mappings?**

Simplified Fluent NHib mappings:

**Customer**

```
        public CustomerMap()
    {
        WithTable("Customers");

        Id(x => x.ID)
            .WithUnsavedValue(0)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany<LocationTag>(t => t.LocationTags).IsInverse();

        HasMany<Device>(d => d.Devices).IsInverse();
    }
```

**Device**

```
        public DeviceMap()
    {
        WithTable("Devices");

        Id(x => x.ID)
            .WithUnsavedValue(0)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany<LocationTag>(x => x.LocationTags).IsInverse();
    }
```

**LocationTag**

```
        public LocationTagMap()
    {
        WithTable("LocationTags");

        Id(x => x.ID)
            .WithUnsavedValue(0)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.Description);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is even possible with standard NHibernate. You're best asking this on the [NHibernate users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers), you're more likely to get a helpful answer there.

Comment: Right; my question should really be, should something like this even be attempted in NHibernate mappings as opposed to the domain object logic.  Thanks for the response, James.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an associative class between the Customer and the LocationTags. Then have the Device use a FK into the associative class instead of to the LocationTag directly.

```
Customer
- CustomerID (PK)

CustomerLocationTag
- CustomerLocationTagID (PK)
- CustomerID (FK)
- LocationTagID (FK)

LocationTag
- LocationTagID (PK)

Device
- DeviceID (PK)
- CustomerLocationTagID (FK)
```

Comment: How would this be mapped in NHibernate or Fluent NHib?